# Drawing text on Graphics2D

Tags: java, size, java-2d

I have made a window and draw to it using a double buffer. The problem is that if I draw some text using Graphics2D at y = 0, it doesn't appear on the screen. I have tried to render the BufferedImage lower down but this doesn't help and leaves a white area at the top of the window.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of how [text is measured](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) `g.drawString("Hello", 0, 0);` will start drawing the string with the baseline of the first letter `"H"` at `(0,0)`. This means that drawing at `(x,0)` will always have at least some of the text out of view.  If you want the text to be rendered with its top corner at `(x,y)` you will have to measure the height of the font and use it as an offset

```
public static void drawStringTopLeft(Graphics2D g, String s, int x, int y) {
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
    int yOffset = fm.getAscent();
    g.drawString(s, x, y+yOffset);
}
```